# Minecraft Backwards Compatibility

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and got thinking. If I were to update my Minecraft from 1.2.5 to one of the snapshots would I be limited to servers of the same version or would I be backwards compatible with the older servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server version and client version must match exactly or you won't be able to connect.

Comment: There are very, very specific exceptions (1.2.4 and 1.2.5, for example), but otherwise this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is only a few exceptions (for example 1.2.4 & 1.2.5) but It has to match exactly, for example, I was trying to play 11.CBGA.ME (Super Craft Brothers) with a client version  1.4.7, but the server needs client version 1.5.